# How can I control the session in PWA applications?

Tags: php, codeigniter, progressive-web-apps

I am building a PWA application and I need to know what is the best way to handle the session. I need the session to not close on the mobile device. The backend is built with codeigniter PHP. I was trying to handle the session with the available variables of this framework but it did not work.

Can someone tell me how the sessions are handled in a PWA application to prevent it from closing on the mobile device ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resorting to using `$GLOBALS` as `$SESSION` is not supported in PWA.

Comment: This would be better as a comment on the question rather than an answer

Comment: That's because of the nature of a Progressive Web Application (PWA) often doesn't maintain state. I would advocate much like @imposterSyndrome to create your own post instead of putting an answer.